# Invoking parent class method without changing code

Tags: java, inheritance

Consider the following code snippet below.

```
class X {
    public String toString() {
        return "Hi";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new X();
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }
}
```

How do I invoke the toString() inside Object class now, without changing the code? Or what I ask is not possible?

Comment: I imagine there's an answer based on reflection somewhere; but it's probably best *not* to want to do this!

Comment: yea, I know.. I was asked this in a technical interview and it left me stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the outside, you can't - that would violate encapsulation. (Imagine `toString()` were really a method to mutate the state of the object, and the subclass wanted to enforce some constraints - you shouldn't be able to skip those constraints.) You can do it from within `X` itself, e.g.

```
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "Hi";
}
```

Comment: Oh well, I was asked this question in an interview and when I told I would use the super keyword, the interviewer didn't agree with me. Anyways, thanks :)