# How to use method from parent class of hierarchy?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Using the following code:

```
public class Animal {
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("Animal");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {   
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("Cat");
    }
}

public class BlackCat extends Cat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BlackCat blackCat = new BlackCat();
        blackCat.a();
    }
}
```

How to use in child class `BlackCat` method `a()` from `Animal` but not from `Cat`?
I want to receive `Animal` in console.

Comment: `Animal#a` is overriden. so calling `black.a()` will call `Cat#a`. if you want the additional information just call `super.a()` in `Cat#a` before printing.

Comment: you have to create a animal object for that

Comment: @KevinEsche So, you mean that I couldn't use method a from Animal directly without invoking method a from Cat ?

Comment: Very related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136701/invoking-parent-class-method-without-changing-code

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456177/calling-super-super-class-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could add an addition function with a set prefix (this case _) and use that as your "super accessor" or what ever you want to call it.

```
public class Cat extends Animal {   
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("Cat");
    }
    public void _a() {
        super.a();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But the question is could I use directly method from parent class for hierarchy directly? without changing Animal and Cat class. I suppose I'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: @BohdanMyslyvchuk no, not if your object doesn´t represent an actuall class `Animal`. If you´d be able to do so you´d break the rules of polymorphism

Comment: @BohdanMyslyvchuk no I'm sorry, in your example the method a() in Cat is [overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) the method a() in Animal. Its a part of the [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in java.

Comment: For more detail read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456177/calling-super-super-class-method